# How to isolate PHP apps from each other on a local machine(Windows or Linux)?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, webserver, lamp

For example, I use XAMPP on Windows and I have the following file structure:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\website_1
C:\xampp\htdocs\website_2
C:\xampp\htdocs\website_3
```

By default, any script e.g. in the `website_1` folder has access to any file on my computer. I want to create a "sandbox" for each website.

I tried to use `open_basedir`, but it significantly slows down websites.